# How to dynamically show and hide a tabPanel in a navbarPage?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app using a `navbarPage` structure and I have one case that I can't resolve.
I have two tabPanels:

- tab1,
- tab2.

`tab1` should be available all the time, but the visibility of `tab2` should depend on the value of the checkbox located in `tab1`.

I know how to add a tab using `appendTab`, but how to hide/remove it?

Below is the code that I created when trying to find a solution.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  id = "navbarPage_id",
  "Dynamic TabPanel Example",
  tabPanel("Tab 1", value = "tab1", uiOutput("CHECKBOX"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$CHECKBOX <- renderUI({
    checkboxInput(inputId = "checkboxInput_id", label = "Show", value = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$checkboxInput_id, {
    if(input$checkboxInput_id){
      appendTab(inputId = "navbarPage_id", tabPanel("Tab 2", value = "tab2"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `showTab` and `hideTab`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
    id = "tabs",
    "Dynamic TabPanel Example",
    tabPanel("Tab 1", value = "tab1", uiOutput("CHECKBOX")),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", value = "tab2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$CHECKBOX <- renderUI({
        checkboxInput(inputId = "checkboxInput_id",
                      label = "Show",
                      value = TRUE)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$checkboxInput_id, {
        if (input$checkboxInput_id) {
            showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "tab2")
        } else {
            hideTab(inputId = "tabs", target = "tab2")
        }
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: works perfect, thanks!